# Automating qlikview charts using selenium

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, qlikview

I am intending to automate the charts displayed in qlikview pages with selenium.As such charts are accessed as image as a whole in these pages its getting difficult to interact & locate specific elements/text on these charts.

**Qlikview Demo link:-**
http://ap.demo.qlik.com/QvAJAXZfc/opendoc.htm?document=qvdocs%2FRetail%20Omni-Channel%20Analytics.qvw&host=Demo11&anonymous=true

**Code to hover mouse over the chart:-**

```
Point coordinates = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='68']/div[2]/div[2]/img")).getLocation();
Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.mouseMove(coordinates.getX(),coordinates.getY());
Thread.sleep(5000);
```

**Code to capture tooltip value:-**

```
String Tooltip = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class = 'QvHover']/span[2]")).getText();
System.out.println("Tooltip value:- "+Tooltip);
```

Though I figured out a way to capture its tooltip value but other than this I'm unable to find ways to locate/capture other elements such as lables on the axis for line chart,legends,etc

Any help would be appriciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is Qlickview Data validation code used under selenium using Java

Step 1. Locate the qlikview frame.

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.className("report_iframe_test")));
```

Step 2. Go to html element present under qlikview frame which is displayed after inspecting element using the IE developer tool

```
driver.findElement(By.id("PageContainer_test"));
driver.findElement(By.id("MainContainer_test"));
```

after locating the element present on qlikview, ex. from highlights section

```
String id = driver.findElement(By.id("32_test")).getText();
System.out.println("after frame--"+id);
```

sysout will print report element value which we can compare against database so as to do data validation.